# How i can change postion of the button randomly in android by clicking the button

Tags: android, button, random, position, location

It gives me an error here that setX(int) is not defined though it is button type.

```
public class TouchMe extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.tuchme);

            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

            btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case (R.id.btn): {
                    Random r = new Random();
                    int x = r.nextInt(480 - buttonWidth);
                    int y = r.nextInt(800 - buttonHeight);

                    btn.setX(x);   // give me error here that setX(int) is not defined      
                    btn.setY(y);   // is button type.

            }

            }
```

It gives me error here that setX(int) is not defined  is button type.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

[View.setX()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX%28float%29) and View.setY() are only available as of API level 11 (Android 3.0 Honeycomb). You have to set [minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) accordingly and compile against API level 11 if you want to use these methods.

Comment: thanks devconsole it works but now the button some time go out side of the screen !

Comment: i try that also but dosen't work:
buttonHeight = 1
int buttonWidth = 1
buttonHeigt = button.getHeight();
buttinWidth = button.getWidth();
int x = r.nextInt(480 - buttonWidth); 
 int y = r.nextInt(800 - buttonHeight);
when i did this the button not changing it's possition! plz help me