# How i can change postion of the button randomly(inside the screen) in android?

Tags: android, button, onclick, location, onchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How i can change postion of the button randomly in android by clicking the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336547/how-i-can-change-postion-of-the-button-randomly-in-android-by-clicking-the-butto)

Here is my code:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tuch_me);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bttuch);
    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtimer);
    timeout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtimeout);
    level = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvlevel);
    tv =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonWidth = 1;
    buttonHight = 1;

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_tuch_me, menu);
    return true;
}



@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi" })
@TargetApi(11)
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bttuch:

        Random r = new Random();

        int xx=getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int yy=getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        int x = r.nextInt(xx);
        int y = r.nextInt(yy);

        buttonWidth = btn.getWidth();
        buttonHight = btn.getHeight();

        btn.setX(xx-buttonWidth);
        btn.setY(yy-buttonHight);

        break;
    }

}
}
```

When I click the button, it goes outside the screen! I am even giving the actual resolution as xx and yy, but it still doesn't work. How can I limit it to stay inside the screen?

Comment: Hi Sangeen. With respect, you are not listening to the advice that has been given to you in previous answers to this question which you've now asked 4 times. Albert Einstein defined insanity as doing the same thing over and over and expect a different result. I suspect that you will not get a good result again. The best thing you can do is to learn some basic Java then do some Android tutorials.  You should also learn to use the debugger. I promise you that stepping through the code in the debugger would highlight the problem in second.  a breakpoint on the switch and step through. Good luck.

Comment: ok sir , i am already learnning basic java and Android tutorials! and i know how to use debugger.

Comment: Why ask it for the fourth time...?

Answer (score 0):

You are using this line

```
    btn.setX(xx-buttonWidth);
    btn.setY(yy-buttonHight);
```

When I think that you want to be doing this

```
    btn.setX(x-buttonWidth);
    btn.setY(y-buttonHight);
```

Because your variables `xx` and `yy` are not random, but you set your `x` and `y` ints to be random ints created based off the values of `xx` and `yy`

The reason that the button is going off the screen is because you are always placing it in the corner by giving your button x and y co-ordiantes which are the full length and with of the screen.

Hope that makes sense

Comment: When i use btn.setX(x-buttonWidth); and btn.setY(y-buttonHight);  yeah it works but when me keep clicking after some click it go again outside the screen! even the random x = 4 and random y = 189 it go outside de screen! can u help me to fix it

Comment: Try setting buttonHeight and buttonWidth to what ever the height and width of your button is(the height and width that you set in your XML) instead of using a method to get it

Comment: i did it too but after some click it again go outside the screen , whe n the random x=316 and y 788.

Comment: Try setting the size of your button in `px` instead of `dp` - dp is scaled pixels, so it is no compare able to pixes in terms of size but `px` should be

Comment: some time at random x=307 and y=732 not go outside the screen